# Testing Splay Trees

Tags: tree, binary-search-tree, splay-tree

I am trying to find an applet online to test splay trees, but none of them that I have found so far satisfy what I need.

I need something where I can input the already constructed splay tree.  I have the initial tree, but cannot construct it using inserts because I do not know the order of it.

Ideally I am looking for a drag and drop applet.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this which can be used as a very useful tool for this:

http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/BST.html

Comment: it leads to a commercial ad

Comment: @blade It appears that the resource was removed and the web archive link also seems to unfortunately be broken: https://web.archive.org/web/20111006184409/http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/BST.html